# Setup project and IIS

Tags: c#, iis, windows-installer, setup-project, web-platform-installer

I am creating a new Setup project using Visual Studio 2010.

I have an existing application which has a few .aspx files along with few other directories. The application has lots of other non-ASP.Net files such as exes and dll's.

I am not quite sure whether I should create a "Web" setup project or create a simple setup project instead?

I am looking for some advice on this.

Any kind of inputs are appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be aware that those project types were removed in VS2012.  Assuming you want to invest in this technology at all,  the "Web" setup project handles IIS configuration.  The "Setup" project is just file copying.

My input would be to go directly to Windows Installer XML or InstallShield Limited Edition.

Comment: Thanks much for a prompt response. One of the things I want to do is to register the web application in IIS. I believe the "Web" setup project may provide some out-of-box features to do that part. I understand that the Setup project templates are not available in 2012 but I would still want to use something which helps me perform rapid development. So would you say that the Web Setup project might be my best bet? Also, I have additional folders that need to be copied under an inetpub directory. So I am wondering if Web setup would be capable of doing that or not?

Comment: Thanks Chris. I am now considering the Install Shield Limited edition for building the installer. Not sure how different it is from Web setup project. Since I need to deploy a web application, so I want to make sure that I select the tool that helps me get things done rapidly.

Comment: Just remember, setup development is development.  You didn't learn how to master ASP.NET development in 4 hours; don't expect installers to be that fast either.  Getting it done right is more important then getting it done fast.  I could list countless stories of companies trashing their customers machines because they didn't get this.